# Is this C conversion to RISCV correct?

Tags: assembly, riscv

Im trying to convert this C code to riscv(64 bit) :

```
int a=10,b=10,i=0,j=0;
int D[200];
for(i=0;i<=a;i++)
    for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        D[4*j] = i+j;
```

This C code uses nested loops and array so thats not easy to convert ...

But this is my riscv code for this :

```
.data
arr: .word 1000

# x5= i , x6=j , x7=a , x8=b
.text
la x10, arr # x10 = array address
li x5,-1    # i = -1
li x7,10    # a = 10
li x8,10    # b = 10    

for1:
    li x6,-1         # j = -1
    addi x5,x5,1     # i += 1
    bge x5,x7,exit1  # If( i >= 10 ) go to exit1
    j for2           # Go to inner for

for2:
    addi x6,x6,1        # j += 1
    bge x6 ,x8,for1     # If( j >= 10 ) go to upper for
    slli x28, x6,5      # Reg x28 = j*(4*8)
    add x29 , x10,x28   # Reg x29 = Base address + j*(4*8)
    ld x29  , 0(x29)    # Reg x29 = D[4*j]
    add x29 , x6 , x5   # D[4*j] = i+j

    
    j for2       # Continue for
    
exit1:
```

Is this conversion correct?

Comment: Are you trying to translate this code directly, or engage in optimizations during translation?  If the former, then there's no -1 in the C code.  If the latter, then do the optimizations in C first and then translate to assembly.  We can use C to do optimizations and check if they work the same, no need to do those only in assembly.

Comment: The C code has an array store, `D[]=` -- the assembly code has an array load, `ld`, so no they are not equivalent.  The C code is incomplete, there are no data declarations, so we can't say too much more.

Comment: @ErikEidt  Yes I just want to result be same and not want to directly convert. For your second comment,I added more information in the C code

Comment: Well, like I said, if you want to go in more manageable steps, then do those -1 optimizations and such in C first, and make sure it gives the same results.  Then translate that to assembly.  Changing your algorithm while translating to assembly is very hard (i.e. error prone) when you're first learning assembly.

Comment: The C has a nested loop, yes, but the `int D[]` array isn't volatile or atomic, and the inner loop overwrites the *same* outer loop elements every time.  So all but the last iteration are dead stores that you can eliminate, and just run one loop with `i = a-1`.  (The inner loop counter range, and the array indexing, don't depend on `i`, only the value stored does.)

Comment: Also, `int` is 32-bit even on RV64, in the standard ABI / calling convention.  Note the use of `sw` not `sd` by a C compiler compiling your C code (with `volatile` so I could enable optimization and not have it totally remove the stores to that otherwise-unused local array) https://godbolt.org/z/s5hj1YK3x